# Quasi-linear Equations,from Fritz John's book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have the following equation with initial condition
\begin{align*}
     u_y + uu_x &= 0\\
u(x,0)&=0
\end{align*}
corresponding to the manifold  $\Gamma$ in the $xyz$ space given by
\begin{equation}
    x = s,\quad y = 0,\quad z = h (s)
\end{equation}
The characteristic differential equations
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{dx}{dt}=z\quad  \frac{dy}{dt}=1\quad \frac{dz}{dt}=0
\end{equation*}
Integrating each of the expressions we have
\begin{align*}
\int dx&=\int z dt\\
x&=zt
\end{align*}
also
\begin{align*}
\int dy&=\int 1 dt\\
y&=t
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int dz&=\int 0 dt\\
z&=0
\end{align*}
combined with the initial condition  for $t=0$ lead to the parametric representation
\begin{equation*}
    x=s+zt,\quad y=t, \quad z=h(s) 
\end{equation*}
now as
\begin{equation*}
s=x-zt\quad \text{and}\quad y=t \quad \text{and}\quad z=h(s)
\end{equation*}
For the solution $z=u(x,y)$ then yields the implicit equation
\begin{equation*}
u=h(x-uy)
\end{equation*}
for $u$ as a function of $x,y$.The characteristic (projection) $C_s$ in the $xy$-plane passing through the point $(s,0)$
\begin{align*}
u(s,0)&=h(s-u\cdot(0))\\
&=h(s)
\end{align*}
then is the line
\begin{equation*}
   x = s + h (s) y 
\end{equation*}
along which $u$ has the constant value
\begin{equation*}
u(s,0)=h(s)
\end{equation*}
Now two characteristics $C_{s_1}$ and $C_{s_2}$ intersect at a point (x,y) with
\begin{equation*}
    y=-\frac{s_2-s_1}{h(s_2)-h(s_1)}
\end{equation*}
it's going to be done $u_x$
\begin{equation*}
    u_x=\frac{h'(s)}{1+h'(s)y}
\end{equation*}
Hence for $h'(s) <0$ we find that $u_x$ becomes infinite at the positive time
\begin{equation*}
    y=\frac{-1}{h'(s)}
\end{equation*}
I have two questions

1. I do not understand How do you get $u_x=\dfrac{h'(s)}{1+h'(s)y}$?
2. why if $ h '(s) <0 $ gives that $y=\dfrac{-1}{h'(s)}$?

I would be grateful for your help

Comment: 1). $$u = h(x - uy) \implies u_{x} = (1 - u_{x} y) h' \implies u_{x}(1 + y h') = h' \implies u_{x} = \frac{h'}{1 + y h'}$$ 2). $h' < 0$ doesn't give $y = -1/h'$. From part one, you see there exists a pole at $y = -1/h'$. I'm assuming there is a condition that $y > 0$ and so this pole exists iff $h' < 0$.

Comment: @ducarita you mixed two languages on your question